# How do I check condition while mapping in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

i want to create one ssis package which takes values from flat file and insert it into database table depending upon there `companyname`.

for example:

I have table fields:

```
Date        SecurityId   SecurityType   EntryPrice Price  CompanyName
2011-08-31  5033048      Bond           1.05       NULL   ABC Corp
```

now i want to insert `Price` into this table but i need to match with `CompanyName`
and in that also in file `CompanyName` is like `ABC` so how can i checked that and insert only particular data...
like this i have 20 records in my file with different `company names`.

I DID LIKE THIS[image]

in lookup i did [image]

and now my problem is i need to check company name from flat file and insert that company price into table  but in flat file company name is given like 'AK STL' ans in table it is like 'AK STEEL CORPORATION' so for this i have used column transformation but what expression i write to find match ...same with other company names only 1ft 2-3 charachters are there in flat file please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are looking to "Upsert" your data into the database.  [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/11/22/lookup-pattern-upsert.aspx) is a simple look up upsert example.  With as few of records in your dataset as you have said, this method will suffice.  With larger datasets, you probably want to look into using temp tables and using sql logic similar to this:

```
--Insert Portion
INSERT INTO FinalTable
( Colums )
SELECT T.TempColumns
FROM TempTable T
WHERE
(
    SELECT 'Bam'
    FROM FinalTable F
    WHERE F.Key(s) = T.Key(s)
) IS NULL

--Update Portion
UPDATE FinalTable
SET NonKeyColumn(s) = T.TempNonKeyColumn(s)
FROM TempTable T
WHERE FinalTable.Key(s) = T.Key(s)
    AND CHECKSUM(FinalTable.NonKeyColumn(s)) <> CHECKSUM(T.NonKeyColumn(s))
```

Comment: can i have any example I'm new in ssis

Comment: The work "Here" in my post is a link to the website: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/11/22/lookup-pattern-upsert.aspx 

That is an example

Comment: Another sql upsert example: http://benchmarkitconsulting.com/colin-stasiuk/2009/02/27/merge-statement-upsert-with-working-example/ 

Here's an example of a slowly changing dimension component in the data flow task: http://asqlguy.blogspot.com/2008/10/handling-upserts-using-slowly-changing.html